# Error when compile to Android in Delphi with Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi

days ago I was developing an Android app and everything was fine and running with no bugs! I dont know what I did that the program stopped working, so I started a new blank Project and I got the same error... So I reinstalled Delphi and nothing, I tried other version and exactly same error!! I was **** with my PC so I formated it and... SAME ERROR AGAIN with blank Project!! Please, can you help me understand what is happening?

First I created the blank Project like this:

[image]

Following the code:

[image]

When I compile I'm getting this error:

[image]

And here is the breakpoint:

[image]

I have no idea what is this, I tried restart/format/reinstall everything and nothing! But days ago was working fine... I will be very thankful if you explain what I did wrong

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your Android SDK/NDK, not with your Delphi. Try another Android version.

Comment: Firemonkey requires a GPU, make sure that the "Use host GPU" flag is enabled on your emulator...

Comment: "Segmentation fault (11)" is the equivalent of an AccessViolation on Windows. Your app is accessing invalid memory at runtime. You need to debug it and find out why. What does the call stack look like when the error happens?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didnt found solution because wasnt Delphi problem... I checked "Host GPU" and worked! You saved my work, thank you so much